# Integrating/switching to MVC3 from WebForms with large existing library of custom controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, web-user-controls

Here's the situation.  We're adding a new application to our suite of webapps based on WebForms and so I felt this would be the perfect time to introduce MVC.

I did all the research about intermingling the two and got the project all set up using an `Area` that uses MVC routes while the rest of the (visual studio) project runs with web forms the way it's been running.

Master pages were converted to Razor layouts, not too bad because there was only one master page that was shared between every application.

The problem I've run into now is reusing user controls.  We have dozens of custom user controls, many of them fairly complex, that are reused throughout all of our applications.  Most of them (especially ones that would be difficult to port) do a fair amount with ViewState and postbacks.

If it were just a matter of rewriting these in MVC, the one time cost would be less than ideal but not terrible.  But since the existing apps need to be maintained and updated as well, it seems like maintaining 2 versions of the same behaviour using entirely different paradigms would be a huge drain on productivity.

My gut says there isn't really a good solution and we may have to abandon the idea of going to MVC for this project and stick with webforms, but I wanted to see if the SO community has any insight on what to do in this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the budget to rewrite those server side controls using the MVC paradigm that would be the best way to go. If not, you could still embed them into existing classic WebForms pages and which would communicate with the new MVC application using standard HTTP/HTML techniques: form posts, sending ids through query string parameters, iframes, cookies, HTML 5 storages, etc... One thing's for sure though: try to avoid putting those server side controls in your MVC views. You will end up with some hybrid application that is neither proper ASP.NET MVC nor a proper WebForms which would be a disaster.

Personally I had to do this same migration multiple times and I didn't bother mixing classic WebForms with MVC in the same application using Areas or some other techniques. At the end of the day it might turn into a nightmare trying to make those two exist together. It's always one of the two: I have the budget and I rewrite from scratch properly or I don't have the budget and I do the new stuff properly using ASP.NET MVC and try to interact with the existing application.

I find it easier to simply start a separate MVC application which depending on the interaction I am looking for would use different methods for integrating functionality from the existing WebForms application.

I am not quite familiar with the complexity and details of your scenario so it is difficult to provide an objective answer but the possibility of continuing to write new code based on the existing WebForms server side controls and not doing any MVC at all for this project might also be a good solution. Writing a new application on ASP.NET MVC just for the sake of it might not always be the best choice.

Comment: +1 There is another possibility to get some benefit of MVC if you do not have the budget for a rewrite.  You can use MVC as an API.  For example, if you use controls with a rich client-side API (for example, Telerik's ASP.NET AJAX controls), you can do things like client-side data binding using controllers that return json from their methods. I've used that method in the past which allowed for better unit testing of the code, made offering downloadable exported data easier, etc.